# c# foreach delegate XAMARIN ANDROID

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, delegates, mono

I'm developing an Android App using Xamarin Android.
Implementing the UI, I've a loop creating some buttons and it's handlers. My problem is thar whenever the handler is executed, the primitive value passed into the method is the reference of the outter value (i).

```
private void MyUiMethod(){  
  var i = 0;
  foreach(var item in itemList){
    var data = new MyCustomData();
    var button = new Button();
    button.Click = (s, e) => ButtonClick(s, e, data, i);
    i++;
  }
}

private void ButtClick(object s, EventArgs e, MyCustomData data, int index){
  // HERE ALWAYS THE VALUE OF INDEX IS THE LAST VALUE
  // e.g. If the list has 3 items, index = 3 no matter the button I've clicked; 
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: where is incrementation for i? I can't see it in your code snippet.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that to the example.

Comment: On the first line of your loop put `var bob = i;` then use `button.Click = (s, e) => ButtonClick(s, e, data, bob);`

Comment: thanks you all, as mjwills pointed it had to be with the scope in which the delegate is executed.